# Laravel migration 150 error

Tags: php, laravel

There is an error on my migration files.But I cant find any solution to error.I get that error on the following system when I run migration command.

```
[Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table 'zadmin_elder.PowerCuts' (errno: 150) (SQL: create table `PowerCuts` (`CutID`
   int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key, `Title` varchar(45) null, `Message` varchar(250) null, `CreatedAt` datetime not nu
  ll, `UpdatedAt` datetime null, `DeletedAt` datetime null, `PlannedDate` date null, `StartTime` time null, `EndTime` time null, `TownI
  D` int unsigned not null, `Distrcit` varchar(45) null, `Geolocation` varchar(45) not null, `GeoRadius` int unsigned not null) default
   character set utf8 collate utf8_unicode_ci)
[PDOException]
  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table 'zadmin_elder.PowerCuts' (errno: 150)
```

Here is my create_powercut_table.php's create function;

```
Schema::create('PowerCuts', function(Blueprint $table)
        {
            $table->increments('CutID', true)->unsigned();
            $table->string('Title', 45)->nullable();
            $table->string('Message', 250)->nullable();
            $table->dateTime('CreatedAt');
            $table->dateTime('UpdatedAt')->nullable();
            $table->dateTime('DeletedAt')->nullable();
            $table->date('PlannedDate')->nullable();
            $table->time('StartTime')->nullable();
            $table->time('EndTime')->nullable();
            $table->integer('TownID')->unsigned()->index('fk_PowerCuts_Towns1_idx');
            $table->string('Distrcit', 45)->nullable();
            $table->string('Geolocation', 45);
            $table->integer('GeoRadius')->unsigned();
        });
```

Here is my create_Foreign_powercut.php's create function;

```
Schema::table('PowerCuts', function(Blueprint $table){
            $table->foreign('TownID', 'PowerCuts_ibfk_1')->references('TownID')->on('Towns')->onUpdate('CASCADE')->onDelete('CASCADE');
        });
```

Thanks, regards

Comment: Is 'Towns.TownID' indexed? From [ InnoDB and FOREIGN KEY Constraints](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html): `InnoDB permits a foreign key to reference any index column or group of columns. However, in the referenced table, there must be an index where the referenced columns are listed as the first columns in the same order.`

Comment: Please do not add answers to the question body itself. Instead, you should add it as an answer. [Answering your own question is allowed and even encouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 1):

According to MySQL InnoDB [Error Codes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-error-codes.html):

> If the error message refers to error 150, table creation failed because a foreign key constraint was not correctly formed.

Check if `PowerCuts.TownID` and `Towns.TownID` are of exactly the same type (integer unsigned), because the type of the foreign key field must be the same as the type of the referenced column.

Comment: yep, both of them is integer unsigned.

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer : ***I know this has been already answered, but I'll leave this answer for future consultation for anyone who had my issue.***

---

```
  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table 'zadmin_elder.PowerCuts' (errno: 150)
```

This error usually means, there is problem with the foreign keys being referenced on the other table, mainly because of incompatibility reasons such as a referencing an integer on a string row, or so.

***Or,***

as it was for my case, referencing on something which does not exist in the first place.

**Let me explain :**

You come to create `table_b`, which -of course- in order to be done, has to create a migration. So you get your `[time]_create_table_b` migration.

Suddenly, you decide to create `table_a` and as with the previous table `[time]_create_table_a` migration gets created, so your migrations folder looks something like this :

```
/Migrations
/---[time]_create_table_b
/---[time]_create_table_a
```

Til now, we are cool.

**THEN!** you alter **table_b** to have a foreign key referencing the id of **table_a**, you migrate, and of course, it gets to the point where it has to create the referencing, and oups! no **table_a.id** !

So you might want to consider the chronological order of your migrations creation.

**In simple terms :**

You want to put a foreign key in side of `table_a` as to reference the id of `table_b` , your migrations should be this way:

```
[time]_create_table_a.php 
[time].create_table_b.php
```

So that `table_a` gets created first, and as the creation of `table_b` goes on, it finds on what to reference!

**In more simpler terms for the lazy people out there:**

1. Delete all your migrations.
2. Create the migrations of tables which gets which keys are to be foreign.
3. Create the migrations of the tables which contain the referencing on the foreign key.

Hope I helped.

Comment: One note on error 105: it's also important to add ->unsigned() to your foreign key in the schema, because increments('id') adds unsigned, too. In my case the timestamp order was OK, but unsigned was missing..